# Unhandled Exception Type FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, filenotfoundexception

**Main class:**

```
public class cfung58_lab03_Main {
//main class 
//creates objects

    //Unhandled Exception Type FileNotFoundException occurs on the line below
static cfung58_lab03_Department myDepartment = new cfung58_lab03_Department(); 

...    
}
```

**Department Class:**

```
public class cfung58_lab03_Department {
    ....
    static  cfung58_lab03_Course[] coursesArray; 
static cfung58_lab03_Student[] studentArray; 

    public cfung58_lab03_Department() throws FileNotFoundException{
      File file = new File("Courses.txt");  //file for Courses.txt
    //System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());//gets path
    //File file2 = new File("Students.txt"); //file for Students.txt
    //System.out.println("True or false: " + file.canRead()); 
    if (file.exists()){
        //if the course file exists 

        //load scanner object to read file course.txt string
                    //NOTE: remember to throw FileException 
        Scanner read = new Scanner(file); 

        //count the number of Courses first before 
                    // creating the coursesArray and filling in the elements 
        int numberOfCourses = 0; 

        while (read.hasNext()){
            //String courseName = read.next(); 
            numberOfCourses++; 
        }

        //create coursesArray
        cfung58_lab03_Course[] coursesArray = new cfung58_lab03_Course[numberOfCourses];

        //restart the scanner system for read
        read = new Scanner(file); 

        while (read.hasNext()){
            String courseName = read.next(); 

            //for loop to fill in the elements for coursesArray
            for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfCourses ; i++){
                //creating element 
                coursesArray[i] = new cfung58_lab03_Course(courseName, 0 );
            }

        }
    }
    //else throw exception 
    else 
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File could not be found.");
```

I'm not exactly sure what's causing the compiler error even though I've already thrown the exception on the department constructor.

Eclipse has no solution to it either.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Where do you think the error comes from?

Comment: Uhm, can you try and stick to Java naming conventions? The way you name your classes makes the code awkward to read

Comment: @mangusta the error shows in eclipse in the main class on the line             static cfung58_lab03_Department myDepartment = new       cfung58_lab03_Department();

Comment: @fge My professor requires me to write the class names like that for submission, I don't know why he doesn't want us to stick with the naming conventions

Comment: gosh, the reason is in the type of thrown exception

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a method, from your horribly named main class, and this method throws a checked exception. So this exception needs to be caught (or thrown, but you can't thow it here since you're assigning a static variable out of a method):

```
static cfung58_lab03_Department myDepartment;

static {
    try {
        myDepartment = new cfung58_lab03_Department(); 
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

That said, this field should probably be a local variable of your main method instead.

Comment: We both had the same idea, I see... Except for the exception thrown ;)

Comment: Yours is probably better. But isn't it what will be thrown by the JVM whatever the actual exception is thrown inside the static initializer block?

Comment: I guess so... Never tried any other way when I do a static initialization block, to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Delete " throws FileNotFoundException" and use "try&catch" to get the error. You'll be proximate to the error line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to create a static initialization block:

```
static cfung58_lab03_Department myDepartment;

static {
    try {
        myDepartment = new cfung58_lab03_Department();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
}
```

Either this, or in your `Department` constructor, throw an unchecked exception instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your code cfung58_lab03_Department you are throwing exception in else case as..

```
//else throw exception 
else 
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File could not be found.");
```

means if your code does not found file on mentioned path it will default throw an exception.

Try following ways to get file "Courses.txt" correctly,

// Collect file with proper known path

File file = new File("resources\file_path\Courses.txt");

// Collect file with Input Stream

InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Courses.txt");